# Error: unable to access jarfile when running script from crontab linux

Tags: cron, python

I have a `.sh` script that runs a python script that runs a jarfile.
I want to run it from `crontab`. I created a log for the `crontab` and I get this error:

```
Error: Unable to access jarfile ArhivareProd.jar
```

This is the line that runs the jar file:

```
os.system("java -jar ArhivareProd.jar &")
```

What can I do to run it from crontab without error ?

Comment: Have you tried `java -jar /absolute/path/to/archive.jar` ?

Answer (score -1):

Check the permission for the jar file
It needs read and executable permission to the crontab user

Sometimes permission not needed when running manually, but needed for Cron.